# Wordpress Woocommerce Page Redirect on filter application

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, filter, woocommerce

I am setting up an e-commerce site. I am using Wordpress as the platform and WooCommerce as the store plugin. I am working with carpet samples, and I would like to have a product search landing page which has a set of filters.

What I am looking for is a way to redirect to the filter results on a different page with the filters in a sidebar.

I have searched for plugins with this functionality and found none. And nothing specific to my situation on any existing sites about how to modify an existing plugin.